# How to fetch list of known addresses in Taquito?

Tags: smart-contracts, tezos-client, taquito

Just like we can run `tezos-client list known contracts` to get a list of deployed contracts and any user accounts, is there a way to do the same using Taquito? So, in short, I've RPC address and wish to list all deployed contracts there.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is not available in Taquito, however, if you need that kind of information in your dapp, you can use an indexer, for example, with the [TzKT API](https://api.florencenet.tzkt.io/#operation/Contracts_Get), you can retrieve a list of smart contracts.